# CSV file and external table having different number of rows

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am loading a csv file in table through external table in hive. The csv has 1000 rows. But when I am creating an external table on that, the table is showing 1219 rows. Apart from 1000 correct rows, table is having 219 extra rows with null values in all the columns. Any one can suggest anything to avoid extra 219 rows? the count i am getting from `select count(*) from table` command in hive. The file is in hdfs.

I have already tried EOL feature from notepad ++

This is my create statement

```
Create external table if not exists movie_data_sample(
    movie_rank int,
   title string,
   genre string,
   description string,
   director string,
   actor string,
   year int,
   runtime_in_minutes int,
   rating decimal(2,1),
   votes int,
   revenue_in_millions decimal(10,1),
   metascore int
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
location 'location'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: are the row and column delimiters right ?  

to see what is happening.. create a regular table and load data from csv using LOAD statement..

Comment: with regular table also it is loading more rows. Delimiters are correct. I can say this because I can see the data loaded correctly. but few extra rows are getting added with values as NULLS in every column.

Comment: Those could be the blank lines at the end of your CSV file. If its editable data size then edit it using Notepad++ and update it. If its huge dataset, then two step process of one External table and one regular table filtering NULL rows..

Comment: It is 1000 data cab file. I edited in notedpad++ for EOF , it doesn’t have any blank lines at the end.